# write data to file not working

Tags: java, file

i was just wondering what I was doing wrong. im trying to write data to a file and it keeps giving me errors. How do you write data to a file. What am I doing wrong. Any help will be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class DistanceFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filename;
        int time; //hours traveled
        int hour;//for the formula
        String FileName;
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the speed of the vehicle");
        int speed = scanner.nextInt();
        while (speed<=0){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid speed");
            speed = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number of hours traveled");
        time = scanner.nextInt();
        while (time<=0){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid time");
            time = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        hour=0;
        for (hour = 1; hour <= time; hour++)
            System.out.println(hour + " " + (hour * speed));
        System.out.print("Enter the filename:");
        filename = scanner.nextLine();
        File f = new File("C:\\test.txt");
        f.mkdirs();
        f.createNewFile();
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("C:\\test.txt");
        outputFile.println(hour + " " + (hour * speed));

        outputFile.flush();
        outputFile.close();
    }
}
```

i keep getting this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (Result too large)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at DistanceFile.main(DistanceFile.java:32)
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting, and where?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (Result too large)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at DistanceFile.main(DistanceFile.java:32)

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this information.

Comment: `File f = new File("C:\\test.txt");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // do something
}` use this to check if the file exists in the specified directory.

Comment: Did you try and debug and find the cause of the exception? Also, notice that you are using a PrintWriter and a File object. PrintWriter takes a File object, and the File object is nothing but a link to a file system resource - which may or may not exist, and your Java Program may not be able to create it on its own.